# How to extract rows, from datatframe, based on column value, to multiple CSV files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have following dataframe:

```
data = {'participant_id': [1, 100, 125, 125, 1, 100], 
        'test_day':['Day_1', 'Day_1', 'Day_12', 'Day_14', 'Day_4', 'Day_4'], 
        'favorite_color': ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'yellow', 'green'],  
        'grade': [88, 92, 95, 70, 80, 30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['participant_id', 'test_day', 'favorite_color', 'grade'])
```

It has 10000 rows and contains data for 400 test participants labelled with unique and completely random ID’s stored in 'participant_id' column. My task is to create dataframes for individuals (per ‘participant_id’) and then save them to the separate csv files (400 in total).

I’ve been trying to figure out how to do it for a couple of days now but with no luck.

Can you please help me?

I am still learning how to program and trying to apply knowledge from data science course. I am using Pandas and normally I access data about individual participant with df.loc, I have also created a list of all of the participant_id’s but I don’t know how to combine both to achieve the desired result automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

You can group by a particular field and iterate:

```
for part_id, df_id in df.groupby('participant_id'):
    df_id.to_csv(f'{part_id}.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you @jpp for this elegant and simple answer. Files are extracted =D!

Comment: I have one more question:). If I would like to use an automatic prefix and instead of IDs 10011, 13652 have A10011 and A13652 what I suppose to do? Cheers!

Comment: How about `df_id.to_csv(f'A{part_id}.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

Solution by @jpp is great. My adaptation based on your solution is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'participant_id': [1, 100, 125, 125, 1, 100], 
        'test_day':['Day_1', 'Day_1', 'Day_12', 'Day_14', 'Day_4', 'Day_4'], 
        'favorite_color': ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'yellow', 'green'],  
        'grade': [88, 92, 95, 70, 80, 30]
       }

col = list(data.keys())
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = col)

for part_id, df_id in df.groupby('participant_id'):
  df_id.to_csv(f'{part_id}.csv',index=False)
```